# Android Radio Button with Submit Not working

Tags: java, android, radio-button

Trying to get My Radio Buttons working, they are in a group so only 1 may be selected at a time, but I want to allow for selecting and instead of that firing the option, rather a submit button collect the results and then call the correct method this is what I have so far:

```
    testRm.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(
    ) {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setReminder();
            displayToast("Test");
        }
    });
```

The setReminder Method

```
public void setReminder() {
    onewk = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
    twowk = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
    onemnt = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
    mag = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);
    twoprt = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton5);

    if(onewk.isSelected()) {
        scheduleNotification(getNotification("1 Week"), 7);
    }
    if(twowk.isSelected()) {
        scheduleNotification(getNotification("2 Weeks"), 14);
    }
    if(onemnt.isSelected()) {
        scheduleNotification(getNotification("1 Month"), 30);
    }
    if(mag.isSelected()) {
        scheduleNotification(getNotification("Test 1"), 30);
    }
    if(twoprt.isSelected()) {
        scheduleNotification(getNotification("Test 2"), 1);
    }
}
```

the Toast Method

```
public void displayToast(String x) {
    g1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg1);
    g2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg2);
    days = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    Toast.makeText(reminders.this, x, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    g1.clearCheck(); g2.clearCheck(); days.setText("");
}
```

the only examples i can find online are using switch statements in an onEvent method so I was trying something else out but failing miserably, as the scheduleNotification method is never called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is for `RadioButton` you need check whether its `checked` or `not`, means like this

`onewk.isChecked()` and not `onewk.isSelected()`